# What file formats does webgl support natively?

Tags: 3d, file-format, webgl

There are many alternatives on 3D file formats, but i need smallest file size + textures at least? I've tried some but i need some advice?

Comment: Which ones you have tried and what kind of experiences you had with them?

Comment: first, most of them does not support any material/texture embedding in them, which makes them not usable for me. But i left this question open for 3 months, and i ve found that .fbx 2012 is maybe the best one if you just compress them with LZMA(7zip). 3-4 megs for 200.000 triangle meshes with pretty big textures.

Comment: my problems with collada is, XML is not the best format for computers, it wastes so much space, WRL never helped me because most of the software can't import well from it, and while OBJ is the de-facto, it does not support any texture/material which i find makes difficut to say that it is even a sane format to work with

Comment: damn, i was really dumb back then, look at those sentences :)

Comment: gltf is a good choice and it is supported the Khronos group. https://www.khronos.org/gltf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm totally biased here (i'm a project member of what i'm suggesting), but you can use the [Blender WebGL exporter](http://code.google.com/p/blender-webgl-exporter/) with the JSON format... models are very small and it is actively maintained :)

Comment: i actually hate blender just because it's GUI :D but good job anyway, i think in WebGL blender can became a standart

Comment: i hear you, i have been "accepting" blender's GUI just because it's open source, however release 2.5+ improved a lot of GUI issues (almost all previous GUI knowledge gets ditched) and i'm kind of liking it now for my modelling needs.

Answer (score 1):

[COLLADA](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_-_Digital_Asset_and_FX_Exchange_Schema) appears to have been used with [some](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/sdk/demos/mozilla/spore/index.html) [success](http://blog.3dtin.com/collada-support). [MD2](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html) is also supported by [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/md2-file-support-in-glge-webgl/)