# How to integrate a 3D professional design in a Web Site

Tags: canvas, 3d, html5-canvas, webgl

I need to develop a web-site when the "admin" could add a 3D design (like a Car) (created on 3D Max, or Blender or some kind of 3D software design) and I should show this "design/file" on the web-site, and all the visitors should be able to rotate this Car to see how it looks.

Just one problem: I can't use Flash.

If I need to do that web site, which technologies I should use to:

- Make the design (3D max, Blender, etc?)
- Show the design (Canvas, CSS3, WebGL could help me? Remember: I can't use Flash)

I'm working for a long time on PHP, JavaScript (native and jQuery and bla bla), CSS, etc, but I never need to do something like that.

Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Models**:
Instead of specifying tool you should specify file format in e.g. [obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) which is easy to read and widely used. You can also try to use JSON which is native format for WebGL with [blender WebGL exporter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627977/1387612). Format is different problem from choosing tool. *Problem is how to pack model to have best size/detail ration to make your site fast.*

**View**:
For displaying your models you will need to use all of technologies that you mentioned. In WebGL you need to create canvas to draw on it and probably you will need to add some styles so CSS3 is obligatory.

In details everything depends on what exactly you need to show. To show plastic or wooden toy car you could use anything like [github](https://github.com/lorennorman/octocat-3d/blob/master/stl/octocat_head.stl) with models in [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) but to render shiny metallic reflection on body, transparent glasses and real looking mirrors you will need custom [shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader), [normal maping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) and [textures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping)

---

**This links will be helpfull:**

- [Q: Is there a WEBGL Manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855405/1387612)
- [Shader school](https://github.com/stackgl/shader-school)
- [WebGL workshop](https://github.com/stackgl/webgl-workshop)
- [3D theory before graphics APIs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/3d-theory-before-graphics-apis)

Comment: Wow. That was a really good answer. So, sumarizing, to start testing if I can do it, I should install Blender, export an "example file" to obj (JSON format), and then find a good library (do you know anyone?) to draw with WebGL that obj-json file... And, if it work properly I could start with the project.

Comment: If you need library you can use [three.js](http://threejs.org/). I haven't used it but looks promising.